# How to use a delegate type property in Xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a delegate type:

```
public delegate bool CheckFormatDelegate(int row, int col, ref string text);
```

This has been used in a Property on a Xaml object:

```
public virtual CheckFormatDelegate CheckFormat { get; set; }
```

I set the property value to one of a group of delegates, for example:

```
public class FCS
{
    public static bool FormatDigitsOnly(int row, int col, ref string text)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

If I set the property in codebehind, all is well.  However, if I set it in Xaml:

```
<mui:DXCell CheckFormat="mui:FCS.FormatDigitsOnly"/>
```

when I run my app I get an exception: "'CheckFormatDelegate' type does not have a public TypeConverter class.".  Does anyone know if there's a built in set of converters/markup extensions like the ones used for RoutedEvent?  Or is there some other way around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding of static methode/function to Func<T> property in XAML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146946/binding-of-static-methode-function-to-funct-property-in-xaml)

Comment: Looks like that solution will in fact work for me.  If you can put this in your answer I will accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is because it is trying to convert a string into something meaningful to the XAML compiler.  You might be able to create a type converter for it (implemented with reflections), but there are simpler ways to work around this.

Use the `x:Static` markup extension.

```
<object property="{x:Static prefix:typeName.staticMemberName}" ... />
```

See the MSDN docs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx

According to that page:

> ... most of the useful static properties have support such as type converters that facilitate the usage without requiring {x:Static} ...

I'm guessing your custom delegate does not, and would require you to use `x:Static`.

**Edit**

I tried it out, and it doesn't seem to work on methods, as you mentioned.  But it does work against properties.  Here is a work-around:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <local:Class1 CheckFormat="{x:Static local:FCS.FormatDigitsOnly}" />
</Window>

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public delegate bool CheckFormatDelegate(int row, int col, ref string text);

    public class Class1
    {
        public virtual CheckFormatDelegate CheckFormat { get; set; }
    }

    public class FCS
    {
        private static bool FormatDigitsOnlyImpl(int row, int col, ref string text)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public static CheckFormatDelegate FormatDigitsOnly
        {
            get { return FormatDigitsOnlyImpl; }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

I don't want to steal their answers (so please up-vote them instead, unless you prefer the property work-around), but here is a question that has an even better solution for you:

[Binding of static method/function to Func<T> property in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146946/binding-of-static-methode-function-to-funct-property-in-xaml)

Comment: The first thing I had tried was x:Static.  I assume you mean something like this:

    <mui:DXCell CheckFormat="{x:Static mui:FCS.FormatFilterDigits}"/>

This does not compile.  The compiler complains that it cannot find FormatFilterDigits.  The documentation states that you can only use x:Static on certain items and I do not believe methods are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest option is to use an interface rather than a delegate

```
public interface IFormatChecker
{
    bool CheckFormat(int row, int col, ref string text);
}

public sealed class CheckFormatByDelegate : IFormatChecker
{
    ...
}

public class FCS
{
    public static readonly IFormatChecker FormatDigitsOnly = new CheckFormatByDelegate();
}

<mui:DXCell CheckFormat="{x:Static mui:FCS.FormatDigitsOnly}"/>
```

I suppose you could create your own custom MarkupExtension if you didn't like the interface

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps.  You can't assign classes in Xaml either, that I know of.  I'd really like to stick with delegates anyway, since this kind of method would force me to declare dozens of classes for all the format checkers.